# layout changes with child theme in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am using a theme for which I want to create a child theme.

I have noticed that when I switch from parent to child some of the elements in the page slightly - enough to destroy the layout.

I attach an image to show this.[image]

Code below.

How can I stop this 'jumping.' I don't think its anything to do with my additional code - because there isn't any! So how has swapping to the child template caused this??? Have i forgotten something silly?

Thanks

here is the child style.css - as you can see its empty really:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*
 Theme Name:   Startuply Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     startuply
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

I also created functions.php within my child and added:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is off topic. Something is causing the page display to 'bounce'

Comment: Use browser web inspector to see what is difference in the CSS.

Comment: yes, I will do - but my question really is how can there be any difference??? I haven't really changed anything!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with working on child theme, But I wondered that could also happen if you have child template being applied and it's slightly different from the parent one.

Comment: the child theme is at the moment consists of nothing except what is written above - that's what's so weird.

Comment: I can't believe it either, running out of ideas, only can say good luck.

Comment: check view source on both parent and child themes, look for the css files load order, maybe there are differences, try to add high priority for the enqueue function by adding a big value like 9999 to the third parameter of the add_action: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 9999 ). what about now?

Comment: thanks Eran. After sdcr last comment i went off and did a compare between the two files and discovered exactly as you said - a change in the order of the css files being loaded. Will try the priority and report back.

Comment: Right, tried that - I can see that it puts things back in the right place, but now there are all sorts of other styling problems. Think I might have to modify the header.php file and put a direct link to the child them css file in there.